# Split a mysql query with php to create a new query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem and I can't find a solution.
I have a little framework to work the admins of the tables and works fine to sort, search, etc. I define a query and it gets the records and create a grid, this grid has options to sort, search, pagine, etc when you search or change of pave it uses ajax call to retrieve the new data, all works fine but when I use subqueries into the query the function doesn't work.
The function takes the query and split it into pieces to create the new query (search text, page change, etc.) but it is created only thinking into queries without subqueries, the function uses the explode function to separate the select part of the from, where, order by, etc. it is simple, so when I use a query with subqueries the explode fails because the query has more than a select, where, etc.
I am looking to create a new way to separate the query without problems of subqueries, group by, etc. But I am not sure how doing it... Do you know a way to do it? I am pretty bad using regular expressions, so I don't know it it can help...

Here is the code of the function (i take off innecesary parts)

```
public function CrearTablaPagi($name='generic',$titulo,$query,$headers,$options=array(),$GET,$mostrar=true)
{
    $resultado=array();
    $this->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    $ocultar='';
    if (!$mostrar)
        $ocultar='style="display:none;"';
    $hayOpciones=false;
    if (count($options>0))
        $hayOpciones=true;    

    /* split the query into parts (here is the problem) */

    //$query=strtolower($query);
    list($select,$final1)=explode("FROM",$query);
    //echo $select.' -- '.$final1;die();
    list($nada,$aColumns)=explode("SELECT",$select);
    echo $nada.' -- '.$aColumns;die();
    $final2=$final1;
    if (stripos($query,"WHERE")!==FALSE){
        list($final2,$where)=explode("WHERE",$final1,1);
    }else
        $where="1=1";
    list($sTable,$order)=explode("ORDER BY",$final2,1);

    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
                intval( $GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }

    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = $order;
    $sOrder = '';
    $aColumnsA=explode(",",$aColumns);
    if ( isset( $GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        //$sOrder .= ", ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= "'".$aColumnsA[ intval( $GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."' ".
                        ($GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }

    }
    //echo "sOrder:\n".$sOrder;die();

    $sWhere=$where;
    if (isset($GET['sSearch']) && $GET['sSearch'] != '')
    {
        $sWhere .= " AND (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnsA) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= "".$aColumnsA[$i]." LIKE '%".$this->real_escape_string( $GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnsA) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "".$aColumnsA[$i]." LIKE %".$this->real_escape_string($GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }

    //armamos de nuevo el query
    $query="SELECT $aColumns FROM $sTable WHERE $sWhere ORDER BY $sOrder $sLimit";
    die($query);
```

Basically, the function take a query and using explode it separate or split the query into parts to create a new query, but using explode is breaking the code when you use queries with subqueries....
Thank you very much for any help.

Answer: here is the changes on the code to make it works.... i still have problems to sort the columns with subqueries...

```
            list($select,$final1) = preg_split("/[[:space:]]FROM/", $query);
        list($nada,$aColumns)=preg_split("/SELECT[[:space:]]/", $select);
        $final2=$final1;
        if (strpos($query,"WHERE")!==FALSE){
            list($final2,$where)=preg_split("/[[:space:]]WHERE[[:space:]]/", $final1);
        }else
            $where="1=1";

        list($sTable,$order)=preg_split("/[[:space:]]ORDER[[:space:]]BY[[:space:]]/", $final2);
```

Comment: There is no code provided. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Give me a minute, iam on my tablet, i will to share the code soon

Comment: I was thinking to use something like this: $array= preg_split("/SELECT[[:space:]](.*)[[:space:]]FROM/", $query); but it not works..

Comment: Good luck with that. My sense is that you've constructed a problem that need not exist.

Comment: you are wrong Strawberry, it is absoluty neccesary when you have one code that works with any query.... maybe you never work as it.... but thank you for your comment...